# PyGtk - Call function when window position changes?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've got a basic python gtk program to show the position of a window, is there an easy way to update it when its moved ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk

class app(gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    super(app, self).__init__()

    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.set_title("Window Position Test")
    self.set_decorated(True)
    self.set_has_frame(False)
    self.set_resizable(False)
    self.set_default_size(320, 50)
    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=4)
    hbox = gtk.HBox(spacing=4)

    self.pos_label = gtk.Label()
    vbox.add(self.pos_label)

    self.add(vbox)

    self.update_pos()
    self.show_all()


  def update_pos(self):
    ''' Get window position, display + log '''
    pos = str( self.get_position() )
    print( pos )
    self.pos_label.set_label( pos )


app()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to attach to the "configure-event" in the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk

class app(gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    super(app, self).__init__()

    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.set_title("Window Position Test")
    self.set_decorated(True)
    self.set_has_frame(False)
    self.set_resizable(False)
    self.set_default_size(320, 50)
    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=4)
    hbox = gtk.HBox(spacing=4)

    self.pos_label = gtk.Label()
    vbox.add(self.pos_label)

    self.add(vbox)

    self.update_pos()
    self.show_all()

    self.connect("configure-event", self.update_pos)


  def update_pos(self, *args):
    ''' Get window position, display + log '''
    pos = str( self.get_position() )
    print( pos )
    self.pos_label.set_label( pos )


app()
gtk.main()
```